# COBOL85-File processing

Tags: cobol, cobol85

I am reading an input file and writing it to an output file till EOF is reached but the issue with my program is after writing the records in the output file till EOF is reached the output file is containing one record extra compared to the input file i.e if input files contains 10 records then the output file is containing 11 records. And the extra record in output file is same as the last record i.e the the last record is repested twice.

So can you please let me know what is the issue with my code.

My program code.

```
?SYMBOLS
?INSPECT

 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. InsertRecords.
 AUTHOR. XYZ.


 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
 FILE-CONTROL.
      SELECT StudentRecords
             ASSIGN TO "=MKFIL1"
             ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
             ACCESS       IS SEQUENTIAL
             FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS.

      SELECT NEWStudentRecords
             ASSIGN TO "=MKFIL2"
             ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
             ACCESS       IS SEQUENTIAL
             FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS.

 DATA DIVISION.
 FILE SECTION.
 FD StudentRecords.
 01 StudentRecord.
   05 Student              PIC X(431).


 FD NewStudentRecords.
 01 NewStudentRecord        PIC X(431).


 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

 01 WS-DETAIL-RECORD          PIC X(431).

 01  EOF                      PIC X(3)  VALUE  "NO".

 01 WS-FILE-STATUS            PIC XX VALUE ZEROES.

 01 WS-SOURCE.
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"202122232425262728292A2B2C2D2E2F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"505152535455565758595A5B5C5D5E5F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"606162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"707172737475767778797A7B7C7D7E7F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"808182838485868788898A8B8C8D8E8F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"909192939495969798999A9B9C9D9E9F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAABACADAEAF".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"B0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBF".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"C0C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CACBCCCDCECF".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"D0D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9DADBDCDDDEDF".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"E0E1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAEBECEDEEEF".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"F0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFBFCFDFEFF".

 01 WS-TARGET.
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"202122232425262728292A2B2C2D2E2F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"505152535455565758595A5B5C5D5E5F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"606162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"707172737475767778797A7B7C7D7E20".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".
   05 PIC X(16) VALUE X"20202020202020202020202020202020".


 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 BEGIN.
    OPEN INPUT StudentRecords
    OPEN OUTPUT NewStudentRecords

    PERFORM UNTIL EOF = "YES"
    READ StudentRecords
       AT END MOVE "YES" TO EOF
    END-READ
          MOVE Student TO WS-DETAIL-RECORD
          INSPECT WS-DETAIL-RECORD CONVERTING WS-SOURCE TO WS-TARGET
              WRITE NewStudentRecord FROM WS-DETAIL-RECORD
    END-PERFORM
    CLOSE StudentRecords
    CLOSE NewStudentRecords
    STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COCOL` does not know that you have reached EOF until you attempt to read **past** the last record.

Consequently, when you read the last record, `EOF` is ((not** set to `YES`, so the next reocrd is "read". That read fails and `EOF` is set to `YES` - but you have already started the loop, so the data in the buffer is written again.

You would therefore need to gate your processing on the `EOF` status. Personally, I'd move the processing to another paragraph and use

```
PERFORM UNTIL EOF = "YES"
READ StudentRecords
   AT END MOVE "YES" TO EOF
END-READ
IF EOF = "NO" PERFORM NEW-PARAGRAPH
END-PERFORM
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked properly thanks for your concern.

Comment: @MohammedBaseet When next you come, you should Accept the answer, rather than just leaving a "thanks" comment. Magoo gets 15 reputation, you get 2. Win-win.

Answer (score 1):

@Magoo is correct.

You have already coded `FILE STATUS` on your `SELECT`s, you can make things a lot clearer by using it.

To avoid confusion, you should code two separate `FILE STATUS` fields.

On the `FILE STATUS` field for the input file, code an `88 (condition name)` for a `VALUE` of `"10"`.

```
OPEN input file, check file status is zero (another 88)
OPEN output file, check file status is zero (another 88)
Initial Processing
READ input file, check file status: if 10 (88) you have an empty file, 
     do something reasonable, else if non-zero, report it.
Loop until FILE STATUS field for input file is "10" (88)
  process input record
  Read input file
End-Loop
Final Processing check file status is zero (88)
CLOSE input file, check file status is zero (88)
All Done
```

This technique, where the first `READ` is known as a "priming read", prevents the tangle of using `AT END/NOT AT END` or immediately testing what the `AT END` has just set.

Comment: Upvoted to counter the unwarranted downvote.  Also, the introduction of "priming read" into the discussion.  I have run into people who were taught that priming reads were evil; they are not, and such folks need to be disabused of the notion.